# ajax : session need page reload to get the latest value

Tags: php, ajax, session, parameters, reload

Hello am implementing a jquery site and i dont want the user to wait for page reloading after every click so a use #p2 to navigate between pages. I use ajax to prevent page reloading and i get my parameter from a response.php page with $_GET method...after this i store the $_GET['value'] in a session in order to use it to the page2...but this work only if i refresh the page. Otherwise the session variable has the previous value before page reloading.

My question is simple...how to get the session latest value without page reloading...?

Or is there any way to pass parameters from page 1 to page 2 without reloading?

Thanks in advance

The code is shown below:

```
function send_an_article_id_to_php(an_article_id)
{alert(an_article_id);
        $(document).on
        ( 
                "click", "#" + an_article_id ,function()
                { 

                       $.ajax(
                                   {
                                        type: "GET",
                                        url: "../get_an_article_id.php",
                                        data: { cmd2 : $(this).attr("id") },
                                        success: function(response)
                                        {
                                            $("#response3").html(response);
                                        }

                                   } /*end of ajax }*/

                              );/*end of ajax );*/

                }/*end of click event*/

        );/*end of document*/                          

}/*end of function katigoria*/
```

Comment: $_POST will not lost if i refresh the page ?

Comment: Use $_SESSION to retrieve the session value from the user using ajax, you dont have to reload the page.

Comment: This code is in get_an_article_id.php page see the ajax request ...  session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] =  $_GET["cmd2"];   When i use this   $_SESSION['id']  in page 2 it just shows the previous value...and only if i refresh the page shows the new value...I need to get SESSION atest value without refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

Sessions have server side processing. You can simply sent request to server using ajax and modify or change session info there. After your desired result you can get print these values and send them back to client side.

You can print value in form of json and make html from these values on client side or simply you can make HTML in you ajax file, sent it to your client and place in your desired location using client side scripting.